# Memory usage difference between reported and analyzed values

Tags: .net, performance

We have a Windows service application which currently seems to be using 3.3GB of RAM according to Task Manager. The memory dump of it is ~3.5GB on disk. The thing is when I analyze the dump with memory analyzer applications such as WinDbg, JetBrains dotMemory, Red Gate ANTS, etc. they all show around only several MBs of memory usage. Also there doesn't seem to be much LOH usage or fragmantation. It could be that when the snapshot was taken it was right before the next GC sweep but there are 3 other instances of the application on different computers and they all show such large RAM usages. Why is there such difference? Am I overlooking something?

Here's the ANTS and dotMemory summaries (comma is decimal separator):

[image: ANTS]

[image: dotMemory]

Comment: The first question is what kind of memory do you look at in the Task Manager, Private Bytes or Working Set? But anyway the rest of the memory is a "native" memory. Memory allocated by a process but not used by .NET Runtime. It could be some unmanaged resources used by your application. But also it could be a memory reserved but still not used by .NET Garbage Collector subsystem.

Comment: Task Manager says it's "private working set". Application itself doesn't use/allocate any unmanaged resources, it mainly uses socket connections and network operations so maybe .net framework could be allocating.

Comment: I'm inclined to think it's the memory reserved by .NET runtime for future .NET heaps extension